# How to retrieve geolocation of Qualtrics users

Tags: javascript, geolocation, qualtrics

any idea if/how I can dynamically (using Qualtrics JavaScript) retrieve the current user's geolocation?
Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the geolocation into the script. For example:

```
var postalCode = "${loc://PostalCode}";
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried it, but postalCode returns as empty.. is loc://PostalCode part of the Qualtrics API's data structure?

Comment: It is a piped field in Qualtrics.  Edit a questions text and click on Piped Text/Geo Location and it gives you the Geo Location fields you can pipe.  Pick one, then copy the piped text string into your JavaScript as I did in the example above.